# Place absolute positioned dropdown relative to global container

Tags: css, layout, css-position, absolute, adaptive-layout

I have this html code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button></button>
    <menu></menu>
</div>
```

On button click dropdown (element "menu") shows. This dropdown have "position: absolute". All my page conditionally limited to container, and nothing should be outside this container, including dropdown. Can i without JavaScript make it so that dropdown be on center relatively to button, but not go outside the container?

Here my css:

```
:root {
    --size-container: 1140px;
    --size-container-col: calc(var(--size-container) / 12);
    --size-container-padding: calc((100vw - var(--size-container)) / 2);
}

.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.dropdown > menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: var(--size-container-padding)
    margin-top: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateY(-60px);
    transition-property: opacity, transform, box-shadow;
}
.dropdown > menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid #aaaaaa;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

[Here my code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvoWO.png)

[If i remove "right" property on ".dropdown > menu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlvRT.png)

Comment: One possible solution is to attach the arrow to the trigger element (the button) instead and show it when your dropdown is opened. Although the arrow will not be centered with the dropdown menu it will keep your dropdown menu inside the container.

Comment: @Guruwanabe, If i understood correctly, i need to place arrow like ":after" element of a button, not a ":before" element of dropdown. But i don't understood, how it will  help solve the problem. If i just remove this arrow, it will give me the same effect.

Comment: Can you please provide the html and css for the whole section. Tried 
 this approach but i'm working semi blind :) https://jsfiddle.net/cb48ynLk/